# jquery extend a json element from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is my original array:

```
var myArray = [
   {"A":"1", "B":"2"},
   {"C":"3", "D":"4"},
   {"E":"5", "F":"6"}
]
```

Then I create a copy of this myArray:

```
var copyArray = $.merge([], myArray);
```

And now I just want to extend first element of copyArray:

```
$.extend(copyArray[0], { "Hello": "World" });
```

But the result is that both myArray and copyArray have been changed.
I just want copyArray to be changed.
They are both changed to below:

```
[
   {"A":"1", "B":"2", "Hello":"World"},
   {"C":"3", "D":"4"},
   {"E":"5", "F":"6"}
]
```

Here is my fiddle to show this: http://jsfiddle.net/LesignButure/GFVUy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if objects exist in your array, the references are kept; i.e.
It does not do a deep copy.

jQuery's extend method performs  deep copy when a true value is passed as the initial argument:

```
$.extend(true, [], myArray );
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GFVUy/13/)

Comment: I just extend copyArray which is a new array.
Why it will influence original myArray..

Comment: You copy the array but the original array does not have objects but pointer to them. So if you modify in any one of them, the other would be affected, until and unless you perform a deep copy

Comment: So $.merge makes a shallow copy?

Comment: Oh sorry I meant $.extend(). Typo mistake.

Comment: Yes, until and unless you pass "true" as first parameter. So if you only do $.extend([], myArray), this will do a shallow copy but if you do $.extend(true, [], myArray) - it would do a deep copy

Answer (score 1):

```
var myArray = [
       {"A":"1", "B":"2"},
       {"C":"3", "D":"4"},
       {"E":"5", "F":"6"}
    ];
var copyArray = $.extend(true, [], myArray);
$.extend(copyArray[0], { "Hello": "World" });
console.log(myArray);
console.log(copyArray);
```

try this..

Comment: its fine! no problem.

Answer (score 0):

`extend` performs a deep copy when a true value is passed as the first argument, so you could do

```
var copyArray = $.extend(true, [], myArray);
```

See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/#jQuery-extend-deep-target-object1-objectN) about this for more.

This solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) to do a deep copy by passing true as the first parameter:

```
var copyArray = $.extend(true, [], myArray);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GFVUy/12/

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery $.extend or pure **javascript**

```
/*
 * Extend Array extra json
 * Example: 
 * $.extendArray([{a:1,b:2}],[{c:3,d:4}]) return -> [{a:1,b:2},{c:3,d:4}]
 * $.extendArray([{a:1,b:2}],{c:3,d:4}) return -> [{a:1,b:2},{c:3,d:4}]
 *
 */
$.extend({
  extendArray: function() {
    return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arguments);
  }
});
```

Pure javascript

```
function extendArray() {
    return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arguments);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
 var copyArray = $.extend(true, [], myArray);

 $.extend(copyArray[0], { "Hello": "World" });
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z9K6F/1/)